# Can different queues be used for events

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, jobs

Hello everyone Can we use different queues to execute events ? Like we do with jobs such as

`Job::dispatch()->onQueue('test');`

Comment: It is correct way. You can use php artisan queue:work test1,test2 for examle

Comment: Yes I wanted to achieve that using Event Listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

queue name in the listener can be set as follows :

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events#customizing-the-queue-connection-queue-name